# ステップ方式を途中で保存されないようにする

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ブログの投稿機能をつけるとして、投稿するのに設定が多いので、ページを分け、descriptionとimageをステップにいれ、3ステップ方式のフォームにしたいです。

routes.rbではこのようにcollection doを使用し設定をしました。

```
resources :notes do
  collection do
    get :description
    get :images
  end
end
```

しかし、notes_controllerで

```
 def description
   @note = Note.new
 end

 def images
   @note = Note.new
 end
```

としているので、ステップの途中でページごとに保存、作成されてしまいます。

```
 def description
     @note = Note.find(params[:id])
 end
```

としても、Couldn't find Note with 'id'=
というエラーがでます。初心者です。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プログラムの経験もあまりお持ちではないのでしょうか？
回答しようとすると範囲が広すぎるので、別解として下記のライブラリをご提案します。

[Examples - jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic)

1つの html を擬似的にステップに見せかけます。
submit を押すのは一回なので、routes を分ける必要がありません。